# XPC Shuttle SH67H3: Unable to access bios screen

Tags: bios

I set some setting in my bios for 'quickboot' or something like that and now I am unable to press the del key (or any key for that matter) to get back into the bios. Has anyone experienced this? Any workaround?
I've tried to [rtfm](ftp://download.us.shuttle.com/XPC/SH67H3/Manual/BIOS_MANUAL.PDF) but no luck (it doesn't even mention the setting I changed because their docs aren't updated)

One thing it does have, but still is not working:

```
The <F8> key on your keyboard is the Fail-Safe key. It is not displayed on the 
BIOS key legend by default. To set the Fail-Safe settings of the BIOS, press the 
<F8> key on your keyboard. It is located on the upper row of a standard 101 
keyboard. The Fail-Safe settings allow the motherboard to boot up with the least 
amount of options set. This can lessen the probability of conflicting setting
```

It's running AMI Bios 2.14.1219 (Release Date: 2013/04/10 Checksum: 14EFh)

Edit: To clarify, the Ami Screen only shows for a split second, then goes right into "Reboot and Select proper Boot device"
(the hdd is a new disk, I just need to boot to usb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That Shuttle model](http://us.shuttle.com/barebone/Models/SH67H3.html) has an H67-based Intel motherboard.

With Intel chip-sets, to get into the BIOS after fully enabling Fast Boot you usually need to turn the system off, and then hold your power button to turn it on an temporarily skip/disable the Fast boot.

[According to Intel](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-032034.htm):

> **Power button recovery**
>
> The power button can be used to recover if you encounter Fast Boot
>   problems.
>
> 1. From a powered off state, press and hold the power button for approximately 2 seconds (release it when you hear 3 short beeps).
> 2. The BIOS will follow a normal boot path as if Fast Boot were disabled.
> 3. If Fast Boot was enabled, the following message will be displayed: "Fast Boot failsafe trigger was detected. Would you like to restore
>      Fast Boot on the next boot? (Y/N)".

Comment: Man, when I read this I got all giddy-like. Sadly, it doesn't seem to work :-( - I tried several variations using the power - 1 second, 2 seconds, etc. No dice...and no beep. Any ideas?

Comment: Whoa. Got it! Oddly, I held the power in until it shut down again. I also held the reset button while doing so (not sure if that affected it). After it booted, I kept pressing the del key and viola! never got a prompt about disabling fast boot, but I did get into the bios. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the new PCIE graphics card that I installed in order to get into the bios. After I flashed the bios to the newest version, everything worked great.